# What SQL Statement can be used to access this information?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm trying to write an `SQL` statement that can be used in `PHP` for a website, but am having trouble comprehending how to access the information.

I have the following tables..
[image]
**Please Note:** `ACADEMIC_ID` & `STUDENT_ID` are just foreign keys for `USER_ID`.

My desired result is..
[image]

As I am trying to gain access to the information from the Students View of the website in `PHP`, I only have the following information to work with..

1. The `USER_ID` of the student.
2. The `DEBATE_ID` for each of the debates the student is currently enrolled in.

Therefore..

> *What SQL statement can be used to give the desired result?*

Comment: Please avoid images when they can be entered as text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.TITLE 
    , B.TITLE 
    , C.FIRSTNAME 
    , C.LASTNAME 
    , D.DATE_CREATED 
FROM STARTER_PACT A 
   , UNITS B 
   , USERS C
   , DEBATE D 
   , DEBATE_GROUPS E 
WHERE A.ACADEMIC_ID = C.ID 
AND   B.ACADEMIC_ID = C.ID 
AND   D.ID = E.DEBATE_ID 
AND   E.STUDENT_ID = C.ID 
AND   C.ID = "(USER_ID)" 
AND   D.ID = "(DEBATE_ID)"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join if you just have 2 information (user.id and debate.id) the flow is from debates_group -> debates -> starter_packs (the join taken from debates.starter_pack_id) -> units (starter_packs.academic_id) -> users (stater_packs.academic_id)

```
SELECT STARTER_PACKS.TITLE, UNITS.TITLE, USERS.FIRSTNAME, USERS.LASTNAME, DEBATE.DATE_CREATED FROM DEBATES_GROUP 
INNER JOIN DEBATES ON DEBATES_GROUP.DEBATE_ID = DEBATES.ID 
INNER JOIN STARTER_PACKS ON STARTER_PACKS.ID = DEBATES.STARTER_PACK_ID 
INNER JOIN UNITS ON STARTER_PACKS.ACADEMIC_IC = UNITS.ACADEMIC_ID 
INNER JOIN USERS ON UNITS.ACADEMIC_ID = USERS.ID
WHERE DEBATES_GROUPS.DEBATE_ID = ? AND DEBATES_GROUPS.STUDENT_ID = ?
```

Hope this works